# How to level out wall before painting

Tags: repair, walls, painting, repainting

We had a water leak from the bathroom upstairs and it leaked down through the ceiling and ruined our wall. As a result the 4-5 layers of paint have peeled off.

The first two layers (brown and green) are thin layers. The next few layers are pretty thick, thicker than I’ve seen.

I’m wondering what preparation I should do to the walls to even them out before I apply my paint. I was planning on scraping the chipped paint off but am unsure how to even them out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it would be my home, I would replace the whole section of the drywall.

Since it is unknown how much damage the drywall suffered it is unclear how solid is it. Painting over the damaged area will not fix anything.

Doing some drywall mud work will be needed to hide the step from thick paint.

Bonus: Opening the drywall will expose potential wood damage.

Comment: Additionally, it will expose any mold that may be lurking due to the leakage. I agree, cut this section out and replace!